# Thread objects not syncing

Tags: java, multithreading, cyclicbarrier

So I wrote this program to run multiple threads of this robot class using cyclicbarrier to sync the threads. Since I had very little understanding of cyclicbarrier I assumed it would automatically sync up my threads, but it seems not. What do I have to do for my Robot threads to sync based on my progress integer value?

```
public class Robot implements Runnable{
public static final int on = 0x0001;
public static final int clockwise = 0x0002;
public static final int counter = 0x0004;
int  opcode;
int moveCount = 0;
int rotation, increment, progress = 0;
boolean CW;

ProgressBar prgBar;
CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier;
Controller c;
Motor m;

public Robot(CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier, Motor m)
{
    opcode = 0;
    this.cyclicBarrier = cyclicBarrier;
    this.m = m;
}




public void run(){
    System.out.println("Running: ");

    try {
        while(progress <= 24){
            i = m.Engage(this, i, increment/4);
            prgBar.setProgress(this, progress);
        }
        System.out.println("Sleeping: ");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+ " waiting at barrier 1");
        cyclicBarrier.await();

        while(progress <= 49){
            i = m.Engage(this, i, increment/2);
            prgBar.setProgress(this, progress);
        }
        System.out.println("Sleeping: ");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+ " waiting at barrier 2");
        cyclicBarrier.await();

        while(progress <= 74){
            i = m.Engage(this, i, ((increment/4)*3));
            prgBar.setProgress(this, progress);
        }
        System.out.println("Sleeping: ");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+ " waiting at barrier 3");
        cyclicBarrier.await();

        while(progress <= 99){
            i = m.Engage(this, i, increment);
            prgBar.setProgress(this, progress);
        }
        System.out.println("Sleeping: ");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+ " waiting at barrier 4");
        cyclicBarrier.await();

    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    prgBar.setProgress(this, progress);
    System.out.println("Engaging: ");
}
```

public class Controller {

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier = new CyclicBarrier(4);
    Motor m = new Motor();


    Robot xRob = new Robot(cyclicBarrier, m);
    Robot yRob = new Robot(cyclicBarrier, m);
    Robot zRob = new Robot(cyclicBarrier, m);

    Thread xRobThread = new Thread(xRob);
    Thread yRobThread = new Thread(yRob);
    Thread zRobThread = new Thread(zRob);

    boolean clockwise = true, counterClockwise = false;




    m.setMotor(clockwise, 14400, xRob);
    m.setMotor(clockwise, 7200, yRob);
    m.setMotor(counterClockwise, 28800, zRob);

    xRobThread.start();
    yRobThread.start();
    zRobThread.start();

    try {
        xRobThread.join();
        yRobThread.join();
        zRobThread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    System.out.printf("x = %d y = %d z = %d\n\n", xRob.moveCount, yRob.moveCount, zRob.moveCount);

}
}
```

Comment: _Since I had very little understanding of cyclicbarrier I assumed it would automatically sync up my threads, but it seems not._ Are you serious? Please read the javadoc.

Comment: I used past tense, I obviously understand now that it isn't the case. I also have read it several times and it hasn't made any more sense to me since my code is not remotely identical to the example they have. They also don't really explain how to split the work between barrier point based off variables.

Comment: The question is, what do you think "sync up my threads" is supposed to mean?  That is to say, what do you expect this class to do?  What does it do instead? and why does that surprise you?  It might help a lot if you showed us the complete program.  You have only showed us a class that uses a CyclicBarrier.  You haven't shown us the creation of the CyclicBarrier, nor have you shown us the creation of any thread that runs your Robot class.

Comment: So I have a m.Engage(this) running before the barrier which starts a for loop which loops increment times. I wanted the loop to go until a certain percentage for his thread, wait and then continue looping until another barrier, 4 times before it hits 100% and I have updated my code.

Comment: P.S.: You could also trim down this example.  You have not shown us any code that calls setOn(), and setOn() is the only thing you have showed us that calls Set().  You have not shown us any code that calls Validate(), or rotate().  You have shown us all of those methods, but none of them looks related to the question of "sync up my threads."  In other words, your example is pretty far from an SSCCE (http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Took out unnecessary things as well now, should be better...

Answer (score 1):

What does the program do when you run it?  What were you *expecting* it to do?  (i.e., what do you think "sync up my threads" means?)

At least, your update now contains enough information for me to make a guess, and I'm guessing that the program hangs.  Your main() routine creates a new CyclicBarrier for four parties, and then it creates three threads.  Each of those threads calls cyclicBarrier.await(), but I don't see any fourth party.  The barrier won't open until four threads have called await().

---

Additional info:

OK, so let's say you have a loop that makes some kind of "progress".  You can have the first thread that reaches a certain threshold of progress wait for the others to catch up by doing something like this:

```
double progress = 0.0;
static final double CHECKPOINT = 0.5;
static final double FINISHED = 1.0;
boolean reachedCheckpoint = false;

while (progress < FINISHED) {
    progress = makeSomeProgress();
    if (! reachedCheckpoint && progress >= CHECKPOINT) {
        cyclicBarrier.await();
        reachedCheckpoint = true;
    }
}
```

Obviously, the program will be somewhat more complicated if you want to have more than one checkpoint, but that's the basic idea.  Just remember that the number of "parties" for which the CyclicBarrier was constructed has to be exactly equal to the number of threads that actually are using it.

Comment: I'm trying to make the threads wait at a certain percentage of progress completed, but it's difficult since then I'd have to stop my program in the middle of a for loop and start it there again which I don't think is possible...Before the program would just complete and hang at 100% which I didn't really mind, but the threads would complete at varying times.

Comment: Ok so I just made an attempt at this and I feel like I'm really close. Updated my Robot Class code.

Comment: I ended up updating my i and increment (which I use in the for loop) in the argument of the method call in my run(); each time i hit a certain threshhold and hit the await command to wait for the others to reach the same barrier in the end. The way you're describing it wouldn't work because it would complete my entire loop everytime I call the method which makes progress. I'll post my own answer to it I guess even though it doesn't make a difference now.

Answer (score 0):

I set barrier1 as ~25%, and barrier2 as ~50% and so on, of how far I want to go in the loop and I update i by outputting the current place in the lop when it reaches the end for each thread. I do the same thing over and over again until it reaches the end of progress.

```
public void run(){
    System.out.println("Running: ");
    barrier1 = increment/4;
    barrier2 = increment/2;
    barrier3 = ((increment/4)*3);
    barrier4 = increment;
    try {
        i = m.Engage(this, i, barrier1);
        prgBar.setProgress(this, progress);

        System.out.println("Sleeping: ");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+ " waiting at barrier 1");
        cyclicBarrier.await();


        i = m.Engage(this, i, barrier2);
        prgBar.setProgress(this, progress);

        System.out.println("Sleeping: ");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+ " waiting at barrier 2");
        cyclicBarrier.await();


        i = m.Engage(this, i, barrier3);
        prgBar.setProgress(this, progress);

        System.out.println("Sleeping: ");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+ " waiting at barrier 3");
        cyclicBarrier.await();


        m.Engage(this, i, barrier4);
        prgBar.setProgress(this, progress);

    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    prgBar.setProgress(this, progress);
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+ " closing.");
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    System.out.println("Engaging: ");
}
```